# Picture not loading properlly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day! I am trying to set a div's background image source with javascript and It doesn't seem to work. I get a weird error in the console from which I have no idea what to made of.

The code may seem a bit lengthy but I will try to make it as clear as possible:

The style basically contains 3 classes. 1 of them is the big box in which the picture and the text are stored. The others are just for the picture (with size) and the label (again with size).
The body contains a simple empty div element which will be dynamically field.

What is left is the javascript file: an array, the object from which the "news"'s different properties will be read (like title, views, image source)

and finally the only function which basically creates new div elements, gives them classes and appends them to the main one. The error is somewhere here.

The entire source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
 .newsBox {
        width:600px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#B3CFDB;
        float:left;
        border-bottom: solid 1px; 
        border-bottom-color: #B9DDED;
   }

    .newsPic {
        width:96px;
        height:96px;
        float:left;
        margin-left: 4px;
        margin-top:2px;
        }
    .newsLabel {
        height:75px;
        width: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-top:20px;
         float:left;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="main" class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    //create the object array and dummies
    var arr = [];
    var news = {
        title: "",
        views: 0,
        srs: ""
    };

    var one = Object.create(news);
    one.title = "Bender";
    one.views = 132;
    srs = "Bender.gif";
    arr.push(one);

    var two = Object.create(news);
    two.title = "Salvation is upon us";
    two.views = 777;
    srs = "fryFuturama.jpg";
    arr.push(two);

    var three = Object.create(news);
    three.title = "This website is a joke";
    three.views = 0;
    srs = "fry.jpg";
    arr.push(three);
    //Set up
    var main = document.getElementById("main");

    function loadNews() {

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var p = document.createElement("DIV");
            p.className = "newsBox";
            main.appendChild(p);

            var p1 = document.createElement("DIV");
            p1.className = "newsPic";
            p1.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + arr[i].srs + ")";
            p.appendChild(p1);

            var p2 = document.createElement("DIV");
            p2.className = "newsLabel";
            p2.innerHTML = arr[i].title + "</br></br>" + "Views:  " + arr[i].views;
            p.appendChild(p2);
        }
    }


    loadNews();
</script>
```

EDIT: The error: `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "file:///C:/Users/SameTime/Desktop/ObjectSetBackgroundImage.html"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short answer to your big wall of code 
change your

```
 srs = "Bender.gif";
```

to

```
 one.srs = "Bender.gif";
```

Comment: Oh god... it is one of those mistakes. Thank you sir, it solved the problem!